# Bitbucket How to replace all the files in the repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, bitbucket

I have Visual Studio 13 project in the repository, but I created the wrong kind of project. I would like to know how to remove the project from the repository, and replace it with another project I just created. If possible, I would like to avoid deleting the repository and creating another, since I have a ton of issues there.

Answer (score -1):

replace all the files in the project , with the new ones ,

git add * --all //will delete the files u have deleted

git commit -m ""

git push -f origin master

as such force push is not required.

Comment: sorry its push -f , but not required